# Planning on Multisite Before Creating A Network

Tags: multisite

On the page http://codex.wordpress.org/Before_You_Create_A_Network, this message I'm quoting seem to be implementing if the "types of multisite network" is **path-based** or **web pages** only. Can you also say that this message is applicable for subdomains and domains knowing that there can be issue on SEO duplicate content, user administration, and URL redirection from `partners.example.com/products` to `www.example.com/partners/products`?

> If you plan on creating sites that are strongly interconnected, that
>   share data, or share users, then a multisite network might not be the
>   best solution. If all you want is for different collections of web
>   pages [“provided that this is a web page, but not subdomains”] to look
>   very different, then you can probably achieve what you want in a
>   single site by using a plugin to switch themes, templates, or
>   stylesheets. If all you want is for different groups of users to have
>   access to different information, then you can probably achieve what
>   you want in a single site by using a plugin to switch capabilities,
>   menus, and link URLs.

Because the way I see it, the biggest problem might be about URL redirection.

Knowing that you have a single Wordpress site that was installed in `www.example.com` and your directory could be `www.example.com/partners`, then in your DNS you have configured to point `www.example.com/partners` to `partners.example.com`, if the link that you are going to give out is `partners.example.com/products`, would it be redirecting to `www.example.com/partners/products` or maybe worst... it goes to `www.example.com/products` because Wordpress was installed as `www.example.com`.

So my question is... Is there a way to go about this? or should I use a multisite if this is the case?

Comment: This applies to all networks. What exactly is the question?

Comment: As I read that page, the text you've quoted applies to *all* WordPress Multisite networks, be they subdomain- or subdirectory-based.

Comment: When I read through your answers, it seems like you leave me hanging to decide whether I would use a multisite or not in my given problem after the quote. Let me just try to finish it off. Give me a minus if I'm stating wrongly what your answers meant. **If URL redirection is your problem, you need a multisite!**